# Error message when attempting launch plotly dash

Tags: json, plotly, plotly-dash, dashboard, plotly-python

I checked the errors and looked up everything I could try to fix the issue in every way I could.

This is the error I'm getting:

[image: Plotly Dash error]

Can someone please tell me what I am missing?

Comment: You can't paste Python code into `launch.json`.

Comment: I think it would be good to get a bit more familiar with Python before jumping into Dash.